# Нужен ли дефис в сочетании "окунь терпуг"?

Tags: орфография

Нужен ли дефис в сочетании "окунь терпуг"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно будет писать "окунь-терпуг".
Терпуг - это род напильника. Название рыба получила за свою шероховатую мелкую чешую. Принцип действует тот же, что в случае с птицей-лирой и рыбой-луной. 
При этом терпуг, с точки зрения биологической систематики, не является окунем - это морской ленок. По сути, "окунь-терпуг" номенклатура не биологическая, а гастрономическая, товарная. БСЭ фиксирует этот факт: "Мясо Т. используют в свежем, копчёном, консервированном виде под названием «окунь-терпуг".

Comment: Иван, спасибо Вам большое, но, пожалуйста, уберите галочку с моего ответа.. Хотела удалить его, но, так как ответ принят, я не смогла это сделать. Пришлось воспользоваться правкой и оставить  только информацию из справочника Розенталя.

Comment: Убрал)) И снова поставил, потому что после редактуры ваш и мой ответ по сути составляют единое целое. Ещё раз спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 3):

***Дефис не пишется, если "в сочетании двух нарицательных существительных первое обозначает родовое понятие, а второе — видовое: цветок хризантема, дерево эвкалипт, гриб подосиновик, птица зяблик, попугай какаду, обезьяна макака, краска серебрянка, газ углерод, нитки мулине, ткань нейлон, леденцы монпансье, суп харчо.***

***Но если такое сочетание образует сложный научный термин (вторая часть не всегда служит самостоятельным видовым обозначением), название специальности и т. п., то дефис пишется: заяц-русак, птица-лира, ястреб-тетеревятник, жук-олень, жук-носорог, жук-плавунец, рак-богомол, рак-отшельник, мышь-полёвка, бабочка-капустница, врач-терапевт, слесарь-инструментальщик, преподаватель-математик, химик-органик, художник-пейзажист, монах-доминиканец".*** [Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111)