# Написание родо-видовых сочетаний: птица зяблик, нитки мулине, газ углерод

Tags: орфография, приложение, раздельно-дефис

*птица зяблик, нитки мулине, газ углерод*

- Пишутся ли родо-видовые сочетания через дефис, так же как сочетания *старик-отец, красавица-зима*? Коснулись ли их новые правила: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7sv51.jpg?

Comment: Похожий вопрос: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/430339/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%b8%d1%81-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%bd%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bf%d1%83%d0%b3/430340#430340

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Думаю, нет.
Оговорюсь, что правила эти не так чтоб и новые, просто это "Грамота" подает все с налетом некоторой сенсационности. На самом деле, как она сама признаёт, это уже вполне сложившаяся практика письма. Да и с 2006 г., когда эти рекомендации были зафиксированы (причем не уверен, что впервые), тоже уже 12 лет прошло.

Но в любом случае, правила, предписывающие ставить дефис, касаются приложения, в котором именно **первая** часть должна выступать в роли некоторого "прилагательного", то есть определения, раскрывающего значение второй части (смотрите ваш рисунок).

***В родо-видовых сочетаниях роль определения играет вторая (видовая) часть.  Поэтому дефис никакими правилами не узаконен.***

Answer (score 1):

Надеюсь, что **пока** всё останется по прежнему, а именно **птица зяблик, нитки мулине и  газ углерод.**

**Всё логично было в Правилах 1956 года**, которые подвели итог развития системы русского правописания за двести с лишним лет. В чем логика? П**риложение ― это определение, выраженное существительным, а нормальная позиция определения ― перед определяемым словом:** красивая невеста и красавица невеста (произношение с паузой). При перестановке слов словосочетание пишется через дефис, приложение занимает второе место, произношение без паузы: **невеста-красавица**.

**В эту схему укладывались сочетания разной тематики:** птица ворон и ворон-птица, царевич Иван и Иван-царевич, река Москва и Москва-река.

Француз-гувернер ― это француз, работающий гувернером; гувернер-француз ― это гувернер из Франции. **По позиции можно было определить, где приложение, а где определяемое слово.**

**Для чего стали писать всё через дефис?** Чтобы легче было неграмотным школьникам и учителям, которые не могут сделать их грамотными. Чтобы всё население "подтянуло" свою грамотность хотя бы в этой маленькой теме.  **Но упрощение в данном случае ― это шаг к примитивному состоянию и ещё ломка грамматики, а оправдывается оно непонятно какой логикой.**